# Openresty nginx throwing zlib not found error

Tags: nginx, lua, gzip

I have installed openresty nginx server. Here is my config file:

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # set search paths for pure Lua external libraries (';;' is the default path):
    lua_package_path '/usr/local/openresty/?.lua;/usr/local/openresty/lualib/?.lua;/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/?.lua;/usr/local/openresty/lualib/ngx/?.lua;/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/?.lua;;';

    # set search paths for Lua external libraries written in C (can also use ';;'):
    lua_package_cpath '/usr/local/openresty/?.so;/usr/local/openresty/lualib/?.so;/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/?.so;/usr/local/openresty/lualib/ngx/?.so;/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/?.so;;';

    server {
        listen 81;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Cluster-Client-Ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

            # for deflate/uncompress request
            client_max_body_size 512k;
            client_body_buffer_size 512k;

            set $max_chunk_size 10240;
            set $max_body_size 524288;

            rewrite_by_lua_file /opt/se/nginx-scripts/inflate_body.lua;
        }
    }
}
```

The lua file references here is taken from http://www.pataliebre.net/howto-make-nginx-decompress-a-gzipped-request.html to support accepting request in gzip format at nginx end.

When I start the server it is started but sending a request in gzip format throws an internal server error with these errors:

> /opt/se/nginx-scripts/inflate_body.lua:20: in function 'inflate_body'
>     /opt/se/nginx-scripts/inflate_body.lua:57: in function
>   , client: 192.168.3.30,
>   server: , request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.3.30:81"
>       2018/06/06 15:08:28 [error] 36232#36232: *1 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /opt/se/nginx-scripts/inflate_body.lua:20:
>   module 'zlib' not found:  no field package.preload['zlib']    no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/zlib.lua'   no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/zlib.lua'    no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/zlib.lua'  no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/ngx/zlib.lua'    no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/zlib.lua'   no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/zlib.ljbc'  no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/zlib/init.ljbc'     no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/zlib.ljbc'   no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/zlib/init.ljbc'  no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/zlib.lua'   no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/zlib/init.lua'  no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/zlib.lua'    no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/zlib/init.lua'   no file './zlib.lua'    no
>   file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/zlib.lua'
>     no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/zlib.lua'     no file
>   '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/zlib/init.lua'  no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/zlib.lua'  no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/zlib/init.lua'     no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/zlib.so'    no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/zlib.so'     no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/zlib.so'   no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/ngx/zlib.so'     no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/zlib.so'    no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/zlib.so'    no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/zlib.so'     no file './zlib.so'     no file
>   '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/zlib.so'  no file
>   '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib/lua/5.1/zlib.so'     no file
>   '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'

After reading for this issue on internet, I tried to setup the lua_package_path and lua_package_cpath manually but still that didn't help. I am not sure what other step should I take to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system doesn't have appropriate zlib shared module installed.

On debian style distro this works for me: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g`.

If you have something else find appropriate package.